# onClickListener triggers after onLongClickListener

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have one `View` for which both `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener` implemented. When I long click the `view` `onClickListener` triggers also, I don't need it to be executed when I do long click. Any ways to prevent it from being executed at time of long click?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`return true;` from the `long click` callback to signal that you've handled the event

Comment: @Rich I tried your solution for a similar issue with no luck.  I'd appreciate any insights or thoughts, located here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783631/recyclerview-how-to-add-onclick-and-keep-onlongclick-working

Answer (score 1):

Return true instead of false from `onItemLongClick`.

> Reason: Return true if the callback consumed the long click, false
>   otherwise.

#### Example:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /******
        Change Here true instead of false.
        *******/
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Pratk Butani I tried your solution but it did not resolve my issue.  I'd appreciate any insights or thoughts you can provide, located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783631/recyclerview-how-to-add-onclick-and-keep-onlongclick-working