# RecyclerView: how to add OnClick() and keep onLongClick() working?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have an `onClickListener` set on a `CheckBox` for a `RecyclerView` that holds a list of CardViews.  The listener is set up in my `ItemHolder` that extends `ViewHolder`.  An initial click on a `CardView` checks the `CheckBox` and toggles the CardView's background color from the default white color to red.  This is working properly.

I also have an `OnClickListener` set up on the `CardView` itself.  The `OnClickListener` is set up in the `onCreateViewHolder()`.  A click on the `CardView` launches a new Detail Activity for the `CardView`.  This is working properly.

Lastly, I tried to set up an `onLongClickListener` on the CardView itself.  The `OnLongClickListener` is set up in the onCreateViewHolder().  A longpress on the CardView is meant to toggle the background color to red and launch an AlertDialog so the user can confirm that the CardView will be deleted from the list.  This works properly but when this code is added to the Adapter then the `OnClickListerner` for the CardView's CheckBox no longer works.  It is as if the the `OnLongClickListner` is in conflict with the CheckBox listener. Note I do "return true" in the itemHolder's `onLongClick()` code.  What am I missing here?

Adapter.java

```
public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItems, ArrayList<ListItem> selectedList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mListItems = listItems;
    this.selectedItemsList = selectedList;
}

private int selectedPos = -1;
...

private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CardView cardView;
    private CheckBox chkSelected;

    private ItemHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1);
        chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        chkSelected.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        int adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();

        if (adapterPos == android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;
        if (recyclerItemClickListener !=null) {
            recyclerItemClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(v, adapterPos);
        }
        Integer iPos = adapterPos;

        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
            checkedListItems.add(iPos);
        }
        else {
            checkedListItems.remove(iPos);
        }
    }

    void bind(int position) {

        if (checkedListItems.contains(position)) {
            chkSelected.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            chkSelected.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent, false);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = new ItemHolder(view);

        itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Handles the row being clicked.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ListItem adapterItem = MyRecylerAdapter.this.getItem(itemHolder.getAdapterPosition()); 

                if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                    recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemHolder.itemView, adapterItem);
                }
            }
        });

        itemHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                ListItem adapterItem2 = MyRecylerAdapter.this.getItem(itemHolder.getAdapterPosition()); 

                    if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                        recyclerItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(itemHolder.itemView, adapterItem2);
                    }

                int adapterPos2 = itemHolder.getAdapterPosition(); 
                if (adapterPos2 != android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    int lastSelectedPosition = selectedPos;
                    selectedPos = adapterPos2;
                    notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                }                    
                return true;
            }
        });
    return itemHolder;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ListItem listItem = mListItems.get(position);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = (ItemHolder) holder;

    itemHolder.bind(position);

    if (checkedListItems.contains(position)) {
        itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(true);
    }
    else {
        itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(false);
    }        

    // **The addition of the below code causes the "itemHolder.cardView.
    // setActivated(true);" in onBindViewHolder method to no longer fire, as 
    // a click on the CheckBox no longer changes the CardView background 
    // color.**
    if (itemHolder.getAdapterPosition() == selectedPos) {
        itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(true);
    } else {
        itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(false);
    }
```

list_contact_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singlecard_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/statelist_cardview_background"  >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardType1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardType1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardType1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardBlankTextNumstotal"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cardBlankTextNumstotal"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:text="#"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankTextNumstotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="actual card #"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:maxLines="1"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />        

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:text="todo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/todo_underline"
        android:maxLines="1"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"  />

    ...
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

statelist_cardview_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true"

        android:drawable="@color/item_selected" />

    <item android:state_activated="false"

        android:drawable="@color/list_contact_item_default"  />

</selector>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="list_contact_item_default">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="item_selected">#FF0000</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: use `chkSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` instead of  `chkSelected.setOnClickListener(this)` and do it in `onCreateViewHolder()`

Comment: From reading many previous posts, quite a few have mentioned that there  are issues with using the onCheckedChangeListener() method with a RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: You can manage this by `holder.vChecked.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` then call `bind()` and then assign holder.vChecked.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() ....);`

Comment: Ok, and the thought is that there is less chance of a click conflict by using onCheckedChangeListener for the CheckBox click event rather than using a second onClickListener?

Comment: Yes, and if you still want to use, try to manage it at single place either at `onCreateViewHolder()` or at `ItemHolder`

Comment: I implemented the same feature. It's working for me.
Can you please try to attach listener in onBindView instead onCreateView. and return true onLongClick implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to solve the wrong problem here. You should **not set click & long click listeners on card view** itself.

- You can have click listener OR checkedChangeListener on **Checkbox**
- click & long click listeners can be on rest of the **view_container**

Here if you want to **check/uncheck the checkbox** also **on click of view_container**, you can easily do it in view_container's **onClick** listener.

**Edit**:
I have updated your layout file, notice now you have on FrameLayout as parent of RelativeLayout(view_container) & Checkbox.

As Checkbox is added after RelativeLayout it will be visible on top of view_container. Hope it will work for you.

Now you can set click listeners **as I explained above**.

**Updated layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singlecard_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/statelist_cardview_background"  >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardType1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardBlankText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardType1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardType1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardBlankTextNumstotal"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cardBlankTextNumstotal"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:text="#"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardBlankTextNumstotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="actual card #"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:maxLines="1"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:text="todo"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/todo_underline"
            android:maxLines="1"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"  />

        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"  />

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Ok so you are saying put the click and long clicklisteners on the id: "view_container" that is in the layout file's "LinearLayout"?

Comment: Great, I will give that a try.  I want to anchor the CheckBox to the upper left portion of the CardView so do I assume correctly that I need to use RelativeLayout for that?  But then how I can use RelativeLayout to get the rest of the TextViews to the right of the CheckBox?  I will update the question with the layout for the list item.

Comment: updated sample layout, you need to use android:layout_toRightOf

Comment: Ok, and for all of the TextViews that are below the CheckBox just set up another LinearLayout and use "android:layout_below"?  If so, is it bad for performance to nest a RelativeLayout for the TextViews within that LinearLayout?

Comment: I also have TextViews that are directly below the CheckBox so the LinearLayout that is "android:layout_toRightOf" the CheckBox will not allow me to have the view_container cover the entire area of the CardView (excluding the CheckBox area).  I somehow need to set up the view_container layout to cover the area to the right of the CheckBox and the area below the CheckBox.  Any thoughts on how to achieve?

Comment: Ok so use a FrameLayout to hold a RelativeLayout as a child view and then the CheckBox as the second child view, correct?

Comment: Hi, can you explain this:  "As Checkbox is added after RelativeLayout it will be visible on top of view_container. "

Comment: See documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

"Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top"

Comment: Ah, ok so that means add CheckBox at end of layout so that it will be on top.  Yes?

Comment: Very good.  Answer upvoted and accepted, bounty awarded.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi, how do I access the id:view_container in the ItemHolder for the onClickListener and onLongClickListener?  Add "private View partialView" variable in the ItemHolder and then "partialView = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_container);"?

Comment: Ok.  I'm confused by: developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.h‌​tml.  Doesn't the stack have to do with memory resources and therefore in this case the order or timing in which child views are drawn on the screen rather than the location of the views on the screen?

Comment: you should not worry about that, as its just small checkbox which you are drawing over your view_container

Answer (score 2):

> How come you are not using **OnCheckedChangeListener** for checkbox?

```
CheckBox chkBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.checkbox );
chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: From reading a lot of stackoverflow posts, devs have had problems with onCheckedChangeListener in the RecyclerView's Adapter.

Comment: so, @AJW do u think my answer is the best match for your Question?

Comment: hehe,,, other guys editted or post new answer after seeing my answer to add CheckBox Listener...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecylerAdapter.ItemHolder> {

...

    public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItems,
                            ArrayList<ListItem> selectedList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListItems = listItems;
        this.selectedItemsList = selectedList;
    }

    private int selectedPos = -1;

    public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView cardView;
        private CheckBox chkSelected;

        private ItemHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.singlecard_view1);
            chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        }

        void bind(int position) {

            if (checkedListItems.contains(position)) {
                chkSelected.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                chkSelected.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent, false);
        final ItemHolder itemHolder = new ItemHolder(view);

        return itemHolder;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder itemHolder, final int position) {

        final ListItem listItem = mListItems.get(position);

        itemHolder.bind(position);

        if (checkedListItems.contains(position)) {
            itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(true);
        } else {
            itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(false);
        }

        if (itemHolder.getAdapterPosition() == selectedPos) {
            itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(true);
        } else {
            itemHolder.cardView.setActivated(false);
        }

        itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Handles the row being clicked.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                     recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemHolder.itemView, listItem);
               }
           }
       });

       itemHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

               if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                   recyclerItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(itemHolder.itemView, listItem);
               }

               int adapterPos2 = itemHolder.getAdapterPosition();
               if (adapterPos2 != android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                   int lastSelectedPosition = selectedPos;
                   selectedPos = adapterPos2;
                   notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
                   notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
               }
               return true;
           }
       });

       itemHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               if (position == android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;
               if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                   recyclerItemClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(v, position);
               }
               Integer iPos = position;

               if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                   checkedListItems.add(iPos);
               } else {
                   checkedListItems.remove(iPos);
               }
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
      return mListItems.size();
   }
}
```

Comment: I thought of a solution like yours but I want to avoid putting the click listeners in the onBindViewHolder() method.  Because they get re-created many times in that method, which could hurt performance.

Comment: The exact thing will happen in your code because every time method `onBindViewHolder()` gets called it will have a new object of `ItemHolder`, so it is good to manage all click events in `onBindViewHolder()` in your case

Comment: Ah, good point.  But that begs a question, I'm wondering if I should or could change the ItemHolder code so that a new object is not created each time in onBindViewHolder.  Any thoughts?

Comment: if you want to do it with the same code, then manage entire data set in `bind()` and handle your `onClick()` in `ItemHolder` by `switch-case`, like for which element you are getting click event

Comment: remove click events from onBindViewHolder() and manage only in the `ItemHolder`

Comment: I have a lot of code (like setText and setBackgroundColor, etc.) in the onBindViewHolder() method that fills in the CardView.  I think it would be great for performance if I could move that code out of onBindViewHolder() section.

Comment: write your logic inside your `bind()` method

Comment: Ok I will give it a go.  I'm off to work now so I will try on the weekend and then give an update.  Cheers.

Comment: Let me know if it not works I can share some examples for this

Comment: Would appreciate you posting some examples as I'm an Android newbie and still trying to improve my RecyclerView code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161346/discussion-between-maddy-and-ajw).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly Please try this code and let me know if it doesn't work

**Adapter Java Code**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ItemHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DemoData> mDemoData;

    public Adapter() {
        mDemoData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            mDemoData.add(new DemoData("Item " + i, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyler_card, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {

        //Check if the item is check and toggle the checkbox
        if (mDemoData.get(position).checked) {
            holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        //Set text to the textview
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDemoData.get(position).item);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDemoData.size();
    }

    public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            //set OnClickListener 
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mCheckBox.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            //set OnLongClickListener
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    //if handled return true if not return false;
                    Toast.makeText(mCheckBox.getContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    mDemoData.get(getAdapterPosition()).checked = isChecked;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemView XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Activity Java Code**

```
public class RecyclerDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_demo);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter());
    }
}
```

Just use this demo and change your code accordingly.

**Edit:**
This is the model class which is used.

```
 public class DemoData{
    public String item;
    public boolean checked;
    public DemoData(String item,boolean isChecked){
    this.item=item;
    this.checked=isChecked;
    }
    }
```

**|REY|**

Comment: Hi, what is the ".checked" code that you are recommending?  I tried to find what its definition was ArrayList and in setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that Model class check the Edit.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to avoid adding "isChecked" in the model class.

Comment: why are you avoiding it any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

you should give you data(mListItems) add a isChecked Fileds!and you can do this

```
holder.checkebox.setchecked(false);
if(mListItems.get(position).ischekced){
 holder.checkebox.setchecked(true);
}
holder.checkebox..setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
  mListItems.get(position).isChecked=isChecked;

}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to avoid putting "isChecked" in the model class.